# Jquery: .onload() function doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, onload

The problem is to check in javascript: if there is an image,to add the padding-left. So in Chrom, Mazilla, Opera that works fine, but **onload function** doesn't work in IE7/8, the rest of the script also works fine.

```
    img.onload = function () {
      $('#text_near_img').css('padding-left', 162);
};

$('#text_near_img').css('width', 300);
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$("img").load(function(){
    $('#text_near_img').css('padding-left', 162);
});
```

to allow jQuery to use it's more compatible methods.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a document ready, so it does the check when dom is ready and check if image(s) exists:

```
$(function(){

if ($('img').length > 0)
{
      $('#text_near_img').css('padding-left', 162);
      $('#text_near_img').css('width', 300);
}

});
```

*The problem is that IE most probably is applying the css settings before the element has been added to stage, hence it will find nothing and do nothing.